# How to filter docs with identical nested property values

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the document mapping below, how can I filter `source-string`s that contains at least 2 identical `targetStrings.score` values?

```
PUT /source-string
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": { "type": "keyword" },
      "targetStrings": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": { "type": "keyword" },
          "score": { "type": "integer" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example index with 1 `source-string` which contains `targetStrings` with 2 identical `score` of 1. I would want this returned.

```
        "_index" : "source-string",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "VHS796CQKuFZo2GPmb1T",
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "VHS796CQKuFZo2GPmb1T",
          "targetStrings" : [
            {
              "score" : 1,
              "id" : "id1"
            },
            {
              "score" : 2,
              "id" : "id2"
            },
            {
              "score" : 1,
              "id" : "id3"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: are you indexing `targetStrings.score` in the form of array ? Can you please share some sample index data ?

Comment: @Bhavya score is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [`min_doc_count`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_4) with the terms aggregation, which will return the
> terms that match more than a configured number of hits

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": "VHS796CQKuFZo2GPmb1W",
  "targetStrings": [
    {
      "score": 3,
      "id": "id1"
    },
    {
      "score": 2,
      "id": "id2"
    },
    {
      "score": 1,
      "id": "id3"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "VHS796CQKuFZo2GPmb1T",
  "targetStrings": [
    {
      "score": 1,
      "id": "id1"
    },
    {
      "score": 2,
      "id": "id2"
    },
    {
      "score": 1,
      "id": "id3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_entries": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "targetStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "targetStrings": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "targetStrings.score",
                "min_doc_count": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "id_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "VHS796CQKuFZo2GPmb1T",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "targetStrings": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": 1,
                  "doc_count": 2            <-- note this
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "VHS796CQKuFZo2GPmb1W",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "targetStrings": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Update 1:**

**You can use [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) if you want to retrieve only those documents that have exactly 2 identical score**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_entries": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "targetStrings"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "targetStrings": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "targetStrings.score"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "count_filter": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "values": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": "params.values == 2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to filter the results based on the identical score condition.

Comment: @Morrowless in the second doc (As per my sample index doc), there are two objects having `"score": 1` (and so it contains duplicate values) whereas the first document does not contain any duplicate element therefore its bucket is empty.

Comment: @Morrowless is your use case different from what I have implemented in the answer?

Comment: You were right, it took me some time to understand the results.